# Efficient elevator strategy

Tags: algorithms, recreational-mathematics

Suppose an institution building has 12 floors and there are a total of 8 lifts.
Now lets say a situation arises at peak times where almost all the lifts are crowded and people randomly enter any lift, so a person going for 12th floor has to wait through all the floors most of the times. Some efficient strategy has to be designed rather than just stopping each lift at each call.

What I want is to design two combinations of 4 lifts which would only stop at specific floors with a constraint that each of the lifts has to stop at floors 1 and 2. What I have designed is that 4 of the lifts would respond only to floor numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and not on other floors, while the other 4 lifts would respond only to floor numbers 1,2,8,9,10,11,12 and not on other floors.

How can I know that this is the best solution, if at all this is? And if not, then what is the best solution?

Comment: This is a deep topic. Here's a resource to help you get started: http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor4405.S13/p14.pdf

Comment: @Math1000 thanks. this is an interesting read!

Comment: Why does 2 get special treatment?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer for a number of reasons maybe, like common recreation area, cafetaria etc

Comment: Does the building belong to the same company? If anyone from 4/5/6/7 needs to visit 8/9/10/11/12  regularly, you will find a contingent of people look to harm the software guy who arranged this.

Comment: @Math1000 http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/ieor4405.S13/p14.pdf is now a dead link, would you know if that resource is still available?

Comment: @Aurèle no its not, I was just able to download the pdf

Comment: @Aurèle The link works for me as well, so perhaps you are having DNS issues or something. I uploaded it here, see if this works: http://www.mediafire.com/file/e3zzsjxfm8u0sr5/p14.pdf/file